# $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}({\sqrt{x^2-6x+8}-x})$

Tags: limits

I am sorry if this is a stupid question, but I really have no clue how to find this limit.

$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}({\sqrt{x^2-6x+8}-x})$ =$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\sqrt{x^2-6x+8} -\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}{x}$

It seems like $\infty-\infty$ case, and I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: For you to check, the answer is -3, you could multiply by the conjugate (see below) and use L'hospital's rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: It often helps to simplify 
the problem by a "conjugate" to make the square root disappear in the numerator. I.e. here, multiplying by
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x^2-6x+8}+x}{\sqrt{x^2-6x+8}+x}
$$
should help you see what's going on.

Comment: I cannot believe it was that easy. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @RaduGabriel no problem, good luck!

Answer (score 3):

$$x^2-6x+8=(x-3)^2-1$$

put

$$x-3=\cosh(t)$$

then

$$\sqrt{x^2-6x+8}-x=$$
$$\sinh(t)-\cosh(t)-3$$
$$=-e^{-t}-3$$

the limit when $t \to + \infty$ is $-3$.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}({\sqrt{x^2-6x+8}-x})$

rationalize. 
$$\frac{-6x+8} {\sqrt{x^2-6x+8}+x}$$
now take out x from denominator, so 
we are left with -6/2.